# Can't bind to 'HiddenFlag' since it isn't a known property of 'app-fog'

Tags: angular

I am trying to share a variable between a child and a parent component with @Input. I have declared `public HiddenFlag: Boolean = true;` in my parent component and in the html i have called the child like this:

```
<app-fog [hidden] = "HiddenFlag" [HiddenFlag] = "HiddenFlag"></app-fog>
```

App-fog is my child component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";`

@Component({
    selector: "app-fog",
    templateUrl: "./fog.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./fog.component.css"]
})

export class FogComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() public HiddenFlag: Boolean;

    public fogClass: String;
    public OverlayClass: String = "hidden";

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    Close() {
       this.HiddenFlag =  true;
    }
 }
```

The problem is that if i try to load the site it says:

> `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'HiddenFlag' since it isn't a known property of 'app-fog'`

If i remove `[HiddenFlag] = "HiddenFlag"` the error dissapears. If you could offer any help it would be appreciated.

Edit: Thx for all the answers. To be honest i still don't know what the problem was but the issue somehow fixed itself.

Comment: It's `boolean`, not `Boolean`. And `string`, not `String`. This problem could also occur if the component itself were not accessible, perhaps because it was not included in a module. As a stylstic matter, avoid capitalized property names. Capitalized identifiers are meant to refer to classes.

Comment: Have you included `FogComponent` component in the Declaration of related module?

Comment: Yes i have they are both in the same module aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **public**. Try: `@Input() HiddenFlag: Boolean;`.

Comment: I'm sure you mean `boolean`, not `Boolean`. Removing public won't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a module problem. Angular doesn't know about the definition of the `app-fog` selector. Your `FogComponent` is probably not listed in the `declarations` list of your module.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [FogComponent, ...],
    ...
})
export class YourModule {}
```

Alternatively, if the parent and child are in different modules, you need to import the child's module in the parent's module and export the child in its own module.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ChildModule, ...],
    ...
})
export class ParentModule {}


@NgModule({
    declarations: [FogComponent, ...],
    exports: [FogComponent, ...],
    ...
})
export class ChildModule {}
```

https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule

Comment: Both components are declared in the same ngModule, so that is not the problem.

Comment: @Nikolai Ah, ok. Well, in that case, I'll just agree with @torazaburo and suggest trying without the uppercased first character on your Input field. I did a sample app to try it out and it does seem to make a difference, although mine didn't produce an error message (it just didn't work).  He's also correct that `boolean` and `string` types are not capitalized, either.

Comment: Tried that aswell but again no luck.

Comment: Oh! How do I forget these things `exports:[ mycomponent]`